# Directions API Live tracking in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use google maps directions API with continuous hitting to the API and updating the directions by getting a current location on location changed listener and it works perfectly.

But Instead of hitting multiple times I need to get directions API for the single instance and write an algorithm by getting the directions using segments start point and update on google map, Find a way to know the user is traveling in the wrong distance and re-route map by calling API.I tried these ways and working but there are a lot of cases to be handled for these scenarios.

I don't understand what to follow and why this is required is, we have a display cycle and the user starts the navigation and directions should be shown on cycle hardware display via BLE.

Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [Google Maps Util Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/?hl=en). The `PolyUtils` class has methods to check if a `LatLng` lies on a polygon/polyline.

Maybe try using the method `isLocationOnPath`. And if it's outside the polyline, make the request to directions API and re-plot the route.

Docs: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/

Comment: Glad I could help :)